# div cannot scroll with height:auto

Tags: html, css

i have made the following example but it does not work.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<header></header> 
<div class="content">
   <div class="sub_content">
     <article>
         <section id="sub_description">some text<br/></section>
    </article>
       <div class="sub_right floatright"></div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div> 
   </div>           
</div>
<footer></footer>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2x3s7o5/1/

i dont want article to take fixed height. i want to take the full height of the parent container. but the scroll bar doesnt work.
can anyone suggest me any solution?

Comment: read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow-clipping) about overflow

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/x2x3s7o5/2/

try to remove `overflow: hidden` from class `.content` and add `overflow:scroll`

Comment: i want only article to scroll not all the content

Answer (score 0):

change article height to 100px.
check it and mess around with the size u want :-)

Comment: i dont want fixed height, i want to take the full height of the parent element

Comment: I tried in some other text editor by changing footer position to the last and this is the output i got http://jsbin.com/siriju/1